# getWindow setBackgroundDrawable Color.TRANSPARENT make background black

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-fragments, transparent

I have an activity with the following structure

```
/////////////////////
/      Header       /
/////////////////////



/      Content      /



/////////////////////
/      Footer       /
/////////////////////
```

the content part open a fragment in a new Activity with the same design , what I want to do is to make this fragment transparent to be able to show the fragment in the previous activity

I have tried this line of code in the second activity but it gives me a black background

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android activities are not transparent by default, you can do so by putting this **theme** in the manifest for the activity you are wanting to make transparent:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.blah.example"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
```